# How to change the text background color of a Comment in Word VSTO?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to alter the text of a Comment object in Word VSTO (2013) but for whatever reason I am unable to select the text via Application.ActiveDocument.Range(int,int) or comment.Reference.Find.Execute(text). Although both operations "work" when you call the .select() method afterwards nothing is selected. So how can one achieve altering the Font or text color of a Comment in Word VSTO?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access it through the `Comment.Range` object, not `Comment.Reference`. E.g.

```
Comments[1].Range.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorDarkTeal;
```

or

```
Comments[1].Range.HighlightColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
```